# Firestore, should I use a single collection for all users, or rather create a different collection for each user role?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, collections

My app should manage different users, of different roles (user / moderator / admin etc.) in Firebase Firestore.

What are the pros and cons of each approach:

1. A single collection for all users, where each document includes a **ROLE** field (user / moderator / admin etc.)
2. A separate collection for all users of the same role (users collections / moderators collection / admins collections etc.). Three collection in this example

One drawback for approach 2, is that authentication becomes a bit complicated since I have to look for the userId in three different collections (vs a single one in approach 1).

Are there any significant advantages to approach 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you never need to search across all three collections (so if you **don't** need a collection group index) then having multiple collections will give you better total write performance.

If you do need to search across collections, then the write performance will be the same.

For query performance it makes no different either way, as the performance for queries on Firestore is not dependent on the number of documents in the collection/collection group.